# sage emacs mode not working in ubuntu

Tags: emacs, sage

I am new to linux. and starteing to use Sage. I installed the sage mode for emacs. However its not working. I am not sure where is the init.el file for emacs located. I added the script given at the end of the installation in site-start.el(or a similar name file) file. But nothing is happening. The mode is not getting activated. Can someone suggest a way out.
Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should read some introduction to emacs and its init file: "[http://wikemacs.org/index.php/User's_Initialization_File](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/User%27s_Initialization_File)" This file is located at `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

So you should write the instructions (from http://wiki.sagemath.org/sage-mode right ?) in this file.